# How to create a native calendar application with categories for events in android?

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

First of all I am Sorry for the question "What you have done"?, Because I dont have any idea about where to start. Now to the issue

I need to develop a native calendar application which enables user to add events to the calendar under various categories with different colours for each category. I failed to find a single piece of code that supports categories for events (I know android calendar contract provider api dont provide categories for events)Then only option is creating multiple calendars for different categories.I read some where we can develop the app as a calendar using sync adapter, but failed to find a good tutorial :( .

- I like to know how to develop a calendar using sync adapter.
- Can I  create multiple calendars from an app (If yes how)
- Am I able to provide a feature to create calenders by user

I am confused, is these are possible, I am very great full to all how provides any link or suggestions even a single line of code. I welcomes any ideas towards this aim

Thank you